# Need to convert JAX-RS based legacy project to Spring boot project

Tags: java, spring-boot, jax-rs, websphere

We have a legacy project based on JAX-RX (REST API) which runs on a WebSphere Liberty. Now we are in a need to migrate our on-premises applications (APIs) to Microsoft Azure.

As there is less support for Liberty on Azure and we faced few challenges when we deployed on Azure, our architect has decided and asked us to move this project to Spring Boot.

What is the proper way to integrate the legacy code with Spring Boot? The existing project does not have the main method. This is quite a big project.

Comment: FYI, WebSphere Liberty is supported on Azure - in VMs, AKS and ARO.  If you have any challenges you can raise a support ticket or Aha Idea if there's a gap.

Comment: Thank you @Graham. yeah WebSphere Liberty is supported on Azure but we face more challenges. Our other team already tried that. Converting JAX-RS project to Spring Boot makes it easy to maintain and library support is great.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I could not find any direct ways or solutions to convert JAX-RS based project to Spring Boot based project but I did follow below steps and then was able to run the application locally on Tomcat first before deploying to other lower environments.

- Created Skelton of Spring Boot project similar to existing project.
- Created required packages similar to existing packages structure which
  was there in JAX-RS based project.
- Removed all folders which were not needed in new structure like EAR,
  DAR, RequestProcessor, RestWeb pipeline_config, ejbrefs-repl.xml and
  other not required files.
- Kept only one master pom.xml and removed all `<modules> </modules>`
  from main pom.
- Added spring-boot dependency in the master main pom.
- Created a main class annotated with `@SpringBootApplication`
  annotation.
- Added application.properties file with required info.
- Initial Implementation of annotation `@component` and  `@Autowired`.
- Removed `@Inject` and added  `@Autowired`
- Annotation `@value` added for service calls.

Apart from these, resolving small minor compilation errors helped me to run the application locally.

Thanks everyone who read my question and tried for the solution.

Happy Coding !